# Error Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure when try to install Oh my zsh

Tags: command-line, bash, authentication, zsh

I try to install Oh my zsh. After install zsh (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y zsh`)

Then I install

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl
```

then install git.

the problems occurs when I try this command.

```
curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | bash
```

this is the log

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   146  100   146    0     0     91      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    91
100  1779  100  1779    0     0    525      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  1416
\033[0;34mCloning Oh My Zsh...\033[0m
Cloning into '/home/icom3/.oh-my-zsh'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 10101, done.
remote: Total 10101 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (10101/10101), 1.92 MiB | 172.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5337/5337), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
\033[0;34mLooking for an existing zsh config...\033[0m
\033[0;33mFound ~/.zshrc.\033[0m \033[0;32mBacking up to ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh\033[0m
\033[0;34mUsing the Oh My Zsh template file and adding it to ~/.zshrc\033[0m
\033[0;34mCopying your current PATH and adding it to the end of ~/.zshrc for you.\033[0m
\033[0;34mTime to change your default shell to zsh!\033[0m
Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

Is there any idea?

Note, that I have tried

```
sudo vim /etc/pam.d/chsh
```

then comment auth required pam_shells.so. However, the error still occur.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Download and run the script separately:

```
curl -OL https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh
bash install.sh
```

And you probably should undo the changes to `/etc/pam.d/chsh`.

**Explanation:**

Piping the text of a script to `bash`

```
cat script.sh | bash
```

is not the same as giving a script as parameter to `bash`

```
bash script.sh
```

By piping `install.sh` to `bash`, bash takes its standard input (*stdin*) from the pipe rather than the user. In this case `chsh` also seems to be receiving its input from *stdin*, which is the next line in the script after the call to `chsh`. (At the moment it seems to be an empty line. If it were your password, you wouldn't have any problem ;-) )

You can test this with this short script, in which `read` expects one line of input:

```
read -p 'input: ' INPUT
echo -n 'You wrote this: '
echo "> $INPUT <"
```

saved as `script.sh`:

```
$ bash script.sh
input: foobar
You wrote this: > foobar <
$ cat script.sh | bash
> echo -n 'You wrote this: ' <
```

Comment: Great diagnosis. I was running in to the same issue on Debian, and your fix works for me. There's a couple open issues on the oh-my-zsh project for this (https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3516) so hopefully this will get fixed upstream too.

BTW, minor nitpick: `curl` prints the file to stdout instead of writing the file like `wget`; you need a `curl -L ... > install.sh` redirection at the end of the command.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Thanks for the (not so) minor nitpick. It is fixed now.